# R: RJDBC: changing parts of a query via the R console

Tags: r, paste, rjdbc

I suspect this is very simple but couldn't work out how do it, nor find an answer on the internet. I have a table `T` in a data warehouse which I want to query through the R console e.g.

```
library(RJDBC)

query = function(date){
  paste('select * from T where date =', date, sep = ' ')
  return(query)
  }
```

However, I become unstuck as `query('01/01/2013')` returns:

```
 select * from T where date = 01/01/2013
```

whereas I actually want it to return:

```
select * from T where date = '01/01/2013'
```

Thanks for any help. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with a double quote:

```
query("'01/01/2013'")
```

HTH

Comment: Ah ha, thanks. I thought it could be something like this. (I tried `quote(''01/01/2013'')`).